# Magento Admin Panel Customization

Tags: magento

In Manage Customers tab, by default last 20 registered users are listed with their emails. I would like to hide the list or change it only 1. This is being done to make sure that call center agents are not easily copying customer's email information.

I am very new to this so, if its not too much trouble, provide full path to the file.

Steve

Answer (score 2):

You might want to go a slightly different direction, by developing a set of permissions for your Agents, so that perhaps they can't access the email in the first place, if you don't want them to see that information.

If you want to modify the page size, you can rewrite this class

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid
```

And you'll want to override this method:

```
protected function _preparePage()
{
    parent::_preparePage();
    $this->getCollection()->setPageSize(1);
}
```

You may also want to get rid of the pagination dropdown in

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml
```

because it will be confusing for them to see it but when they use it for it to not function.

Comment: @user1538621, sure no problem!  Feel free to mark my answer with the green checkmark :)